# Why this recursive function only work when used ELSE

Tags: c++, recursion

I made this function that returns the number of digits in an integer:
it works fine when I used ELSE to return the count

```
int getIndex(int number, int count) {   // at first call count is 0
 number /= 10;
if (number > 0){

    getIndex(number,++count);

               }
else{
    return ++count;
    }   
}
```

but when I first tried to execute without ELSE statement I thought function will be called recursively till IF condition is not met and then only it will encounter the return statement

And function will exit there as integer is returned, but 
actually

if the number contains more than one digit, doesn't matter how many time it increase with recursive call  it outputs 2

Just curious where as to why I am getting my concept wrong

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: are you aware that C and C++ are two different languages?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm aware, but if I'm not wrong, Syntax used in this above function will work both in c and c++

Comment: That's OK, but still, you need to choose one, just because the syntax is similar does not mean the rules will be same, in general. :)

Comment: You should turn up your compilers warning levels to maximum

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj: So? You're still either writing C or writing C++, and the solution/answer may differ depending on which it is. So just tag the language you're _actually_ using, instead of making assumptions based on apparent co-incidences! Also not sure why you felt the need to capitalise the word "concept".

Comment: @BoundaryImposition removed tag of C,
and I  capitalise "concept" because I don't just need code but wanted to know the reason and concept behind the behaviour,
So just to simply putting weight on that word  capitalised it

Comment: Capitals are not for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it works fine when I used ELSE

Actually, the behaviour of the shown program is undefined. If the `if` branch is entered, then no `return` statement will be reached, and the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

When you remove the else statement and instead return unconditionally, the behaviour is well defined: The function will always return `count + 1` or `count + 2` depending on the value of `number` (which isn't correct).

---

Consider this, where do you use the value of the recursive function call? Nowhere; you simply discard the value. Would it make sense to return that value to the caller? Yes, it would. If only you returned within the `if` branch, the behaviour would be correct.

```
return getIndex(number,++count);
```

Then it won't matter whether the recursion-terminating branch is within else or not, it will only be executed if the `if` branch is not executed:

Comment: This is correct.  If you ignore the `if` condition, you incorrectly increment the count before returning the result.  If you just return the count your results would be fine.  Now if you take into consideration the `if` you get the recursive behavior you want.

Comment: With that last line, I think my concept is cleared, This is what I wanted to get cleared,  without else ++count would be returned but by using return with recursive call  value of count got from recursive call is returned, IS this correct

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `return` before the recursive call.
By default, it returns 0 (for some compilers).

### Edit:

But actually the code should have looked like this:

```c
int getIndex(int number) {
    if (number > 0) {
        return getIndex(number/10) + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: In C++, besides main, missing a return statement is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver just confirming, even if the returned value is not used?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes.  `int bar() {} ... bar();`is still UB.